# i-report 3.7.6 error while editing JRXML

Tags: java, xml, ireport

I have a problem with editing XML files with i-Report 3.7.6. My XML file was created with i-Report 2.0.2 and later saved in JRXML format with i-Report 3.7.6. When I click on the XML file now, i-Report gives me the error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Assertion failed!

Program: ...rogram Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\bin\java.exe
File: ../../../src/share/native/sun/font/t2k/t2kstrm.c
Line: 132

Expression: pos <= t->maxPos

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)
---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this text (or similar from another template) in `XML` mode after `<kbd><</kbd>property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>`:

```
<kbd><</kbd>style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
<kbd><</kbd>style name="Sans_Bold" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
<kbd><</kbd>style name="Sans_Italic" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Assertion means that your fonts are corrupted