# creating jar files for non .class files

Tags: java, jar

i'm trying to create a jar file for non .class files. I am following the same process just like for creating a jar file for .class files but using *.*

like jar -cvf loanReports.jar asterik.asterik *.*

but i'm getting an exception. what am i missing?

Comment: Aren't jars just zip files with an extention of jar?

Comment: Details are important.  What exceptions are you getting? And when?

Comment: the exception is as follows:java.io.IOException:invalid header field at java.util.jar.Manifest.init Manifest.java  since i'm not creating a jar file for .class files i didn't add a manifest file. exception occurs while creating the jar from cmd in windows.

Comment: Your command looks correct(I'm not getting exception on mu local box while executin it). Please post full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the files in a directory and go to the directory and use following command jar -cvf ../loanReporter.jar *

Comment: i was having similar other problems and with ireports 3.7.6 just like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345981/i-report-3-7-6-error-while-editing-jrxml    .....out of wits...i completely formatted the system and now the same command works.... i really dont have an idea about what went wrong....but anyways thanks guys for trying to help me.